# pm-utils: No network in suspend scripts?

Tags: linux, debian, power-management

I'd like to put a script in `/etc/pm/suspend.d/` that needs network access (for a very short time) before allowing the system to suspend. However, even with scripts named "001_something" in `/etc/pm/suspend.d/` and `/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/` I do not get any network access. It seems this is disabled before the scripts are run.

Why is networking disabled? How can I enable it?

Also, I am unable to make use of the pm-suspend.log in `/var/log`. It seems the file for the suspend part is overwritten as soon as the system is resumed?

The following has been observed in `daemon.log`:

```
Feb 7 22:09:04 zenbook NetworkManager[3606]: <info> sleep requested (sleeping: no enabled: yes)·
Feb 7 22:09:04 zenbook NetworkManager[3606]: <info> sleeping or disabling...·
Feb 7 22:09:04 zenbook NetworkManager[3606]: <info> (wlan0): now unmanaged·
Feb 7 22:09:04 zenbook NetworkManager[3606]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: activated -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping') [100 10 37]·
Feb 7 22:09:04 zenbook NetworkManager[3606]: <info> (wlan0): deactivating device (reason 'sleeping') [37]·
```

I am using Debian Testing with Gnome 3.

EDIT: The problem is not related to pm-utils. As far as I know, NetworkManager disables the network (in nm-manager.c:do_sleep_wake). I don't know how to solve this, yet. See [NetworkManager: disabled network when sending system to sleep](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/64151/networkmanager-disabled-network-when-sending-system-to-sleep)

Comment: More Info: I'm using a wireless network using NetworkManager.

Comment: Migrated on behalf of the OP.

Comment: Maybe your script gets run too late, after network shutdown?

Comment: I think so, yes. But how can I run it earlier?

Comment: I might have confused `sleep.d` with `suspend.d` in the question, but this is not the source of the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### 1. Quirks?

First I would confirm that your suspend is functioning correctly. Take a look at the quirks page and confirm that your suspend is functioning correctly and not just seeming like it's working right.

- [Sleep Quirk Debugger](http://hal.freedesktop.org/quirk/quirk-suspend-try.html)

#### 2. Is your 001_something script executable?

Check to make sure that your `001_something` script is executable!

```
% chmod +x 001_something
```

#### 3. Does your 001_something script look correct?

Check to make sure your script conforms to what `pm-utils` is expecting.

*Example script*

```
#!/bin/bash
case "$1" in
    hibernate|suspend)
        ACTION BEFORE SUSPEND/HIBERNATE
        ;;
    thaw|resume)
        ACTION AFTER RESUME
        ;;
    *)
        ;;
esac
exit $?
```

**NOTE:** Are you putting your attempts to use the network in the `hibernate|suspend` correct portion of the case/switch statement?

#### 4. file in .d directory functioning (/etc/pm/suspend.d/ or /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/)?

Next I would confirm that your `001_something` script is in fact getting picked up by suspend/hibernate correctly by having it simply echo out to a file some string just so you know that it's working.

```
echo "yup I'm working" > /tmp/pmck_`date +%Y-%T`.log
```

You should then see files such as `pmck_2013-16:08:11.log` in `/tmp`.

#### 5. /var/log?

If the above **.d** directory is functioning, I would make a `001_something` and have it copy the `/var/log/pm-suspend.log` file you think is getting overwritten to some other file under `/tmp`, that way you can at least confirm that logging is correct. This may gain you some further insight into what's happening.

```
cp /var/log/pm-suspend.log /tmp/pmlg_`date +%Y-%T`.log
```

#### 6. Sleep hook number?

Also can you change the name of your hook file to `00-something` instead of `001_something`? Not sure but the man page indicates these values.

```
SLEEP HOOK ORDERING CONVENTION
       00 - 49
           User and most package supplied hooks. If a hook assumes that all of the usual services and userspace infrastructure
           is still running, it should be here.

       50 - 74
           Service handling hooks. Hooks that start or stop a service belong in this range. At or before 50, hooks can assume
           that all services are still enabled.

       75 - 89
           Module and non-core hardware handling. If a hook needs to load/unload a module, or if it needs to place non-video
           hardware that would otherwise break suspend or hibernate into a safe state, it belongs in this range. At or before
           75, hooks can assume all modules are still loaded.

       90 - 99
           Reserved for critical suspend hooks.
```

#### 7. Network connectivity?

Add the following to your `001_something` script:

```
TMP=/tmp/pmip_`date +%Y-%T`.log

# network status?
ip link show > $TMP

# dns working?
dig google.com +answer >> $TMP

# can we ping google?
ping -c 5 www.google.com >> $TMP
```

#### 8. Bug with pm-utils, HAL, and Wheezy?

I came across [this debian bug report](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=649871) and wonder if this might be the cause of your problem. The bug describes an issue with HAL and pm-utils. It sounds like removing HAL fixes the networking issue.

#### 9. More verbose pm-utils debugging

Additionally there is [this link](http://wiki.debian.org/Suspend) which offers advice for suspend/resume issues specific to Debian. There is mention of a way to increase the logging of pm-utils by setting a variable, `PM_DEBUG=true` in the `/usr/lib/pm-utils/pm-functions` file.

*excerpt*

> Enabling Debugging for pm-utils
>
> The log of suspend and resume processes are in file
>   /var/log/pm-suspend.log. It contains moderately verbose information by
>   default. More information can be enabled for debugging by inserting
>   line export PM_DEBUG=true into the beginning of file
>   /usr/lib/pm-utils/pm-functions.

Perhaps this might be helpful in giving you more insight into what's going on with pm-utils!

#### 10. ACPI shutting down network prior to `pm-utils`?

If the issue doesn't appear to be with `pm-utils`, it may be because of `acpi`. When you close the lid on your laptop, an `acpi` event is triggered, that event has an action associated to it.

#### EVENT File

```
% more /etc/acpi/events/lm_lid
event=button[ /]lid
action=/etc/acpi/actions/lm_lid.sh %e
```

#### ACTION File

```
% more /etc/acpi/actions/lm_lid.sh
#! /bin/sh

test -f /usr/sbin/laptop_mode || exit 0

# lid button pressed/released event handler

/usr/sbin/laptop_mode auto
```

Taking a closer look at `laptop_mode` you'll see that this tool is responsible for doing a variety of things, one of which is managing the status of your network devices.

laptop-mode maintains a directory, `/etc/laptop-mode/conf.d`, similar to other unix tools. In there are files related to the ethernet and wireless networking devices.

In the primary config. file, `/etc/laptop-mode/laptop-mode.conf`, is the ability to turn on more verbose messaging. Perhaps this will shed some additional light on what's going on?

```
VERBOSE_OUTPUT=1
```

### Summary of above things to try based on the OP's feedback

**1:** Suspend works as far as battery usage and the sleep LED on my notebook are concerned. Otherwise I do not understand how the mentioned web page should help me find out.

**2:** It is.

**3:** It looks correct.

**4:** I get those files.

**5:** I get the corresponding log files, but these are not helpful to me.

**6:** 00 instead of 001 does not show any difference.

**7:** Things in this section just test for network connectivity. As said in my question, I do not have network connectivity as soon as the script is run. The wlan0 device is down. The log files: http://paste.debian.net/231760.

**NOTE:** I did not have dig installed (error msg. in paste.debian.net log), however it is clear that no network access is available (as said). I can see that it is down by inspecting the output of iwconfig, ip link show, ping, ... The perl script is the script in question.

BTW, as soon as the first line of `/usr/lib/pm-utils/bin/pm-action` is executed (from upowerd), the network is down already.

**8:** hal was installed, removing it does not change anything.

Comment: Numbering is important. I first tried to name my script as "001_blah.sh" and it was not picked up. It was only picked up after I renamed it to "00_blah.sh". Thanks for the detailed answer BTW.