# NetworkManager: disabled network when sending system to sleep

Tags: networkmanager, power-management

When I suspend my notebook, `NetworkManager` disables the wireless network (in `nm-manager.c:do_sleep_wake`).

However, I'd love to still use the network for a very short time (to unmount `cifs` mounts, that otherwise make my system unusable when resuming).

How can I make `NetworkManager` *not* disable my network? Is it possible to wait a few seconds (or until something is triggered; or a lock is released)?

Related: [pm-utils: No network in suspend scripts?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62157/pm-utils-no-network-in-suspend-scripts/63498#63498)

debug log:

```
Feb  8 10:03:23 zenbook NetworkManager[3606]: <debug> [1360314203.373226] [nm-manager.c:3391] upower_sleeping_cb(): Received UPower sleeping signal
Feb  8 10:03:23 zenbook NetworkManager[3606]: <info> sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
Feb  8 10:03:23 zenbook NetworkManager[3606]: <info> sleeping or disabling...
Feb  8 10:03:23 zenbook NetworkManager[3606]: <info> (wlan0): now unmanaged
```

EDIT: To make it clear, having scripts in `/etc/pm/sleep.d` does not help as the network already is disabled as soon as a script is executed.

Comment: Take a look at the power management options and look for something to the effect of "disable networking when computer is suspended"

Comment: There is no such thing. I am using xmonad with Gnome 3.

Comment: you mean you're replacing the GNOME Shell with xmonad, but not changing anything else? if so, the power options are in the "Power" pane of `gnome-control-center`.

Comment: I know. There is no such thing as you said.

Comment: The Q you're asking is a bit of an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), The answer I provided to you last year, http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62157/pm-utils-no-network-in-suspend-scripts, wrt creating custom job hooks tied to power management suspend/resume is the way to go here. Trying to prop the network up a little bit longer isn't the right way to approach this problem.

Comment: The answer you provided to the mentioned post sadly did not help at all (although it was quite long). I asked to have network connectivity in a script, which I still do not have. Adding hooks does not help if I don't have network access.

Comment: Regarding having a XY problem: The straightforward solution would to modify the kernel / SMB / CIFS so that a disrupted network (on sleep) does not crash the network system on resume. However, I feel unable to solve this issue.

Answer (score 4):

I do not know if it's standard, but in Ubuntu there are script that are run before suspend / after resume in `/etc/pm/sleep.d` and in `/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d`. In my system seems that the network is shut down by `/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/60_wpa_supplicant`.

You can write a script for example `/etc/pm/sleep.d/10-umount` to unmount your shares before suspend. The structure of these scripts is like that:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
case "${1}" in
        suspend|hibernate)
                # your command to umount here 
                ;;
        resume|thaw)
                # (possibly) your command to mount here
                ;;
esac
```

Notice that if the script return a generic error the suspend is aborted, so take care of this (especially is you, like me, use to close the lid and store the laptop away... ). To script more complex things, thanks to Samuel Peter for his comment:

> you can return an error without aborting the suspend by returning one
>   of the special values defined in `/usr/lib/pm-utils/pm-functions` : `$NA`
>   is "not applicable", `$DX` is "disabled", and `$NX` is "not executable".
>   See the `hook_exit_status` function in the pm-functions script

You could even remount them after resume automatically; from [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/pm-utils) I found that:

> If you want to do something specific to your setup during suspend or
>   hibernate, then you can easily put your own hook into /etc/pm/sleep.d.
>   The hooks in this directory will be called in alphabetic order during
>   suspend (that is the reason their names all start with 2 digits, to
>   make the ordering explicit) and in the reverse order during resume.

So putting in the same script the `umount` and `mount command` should work (in suspend it is executed before shutting down network, and in resume after that).

The [link in your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62157/pm-utils-no-network-in-suspend-scripts/63498#63498)  is revealing; it is my interpretation that if NetworkManager shuts down the network before the scripts at level 00-50 are run it is a bug --- at least if the connection is marked as a system connection (in Network Settings -> Options -> Identity -> Make available to other user).

Comment: +1 `pm-utils` should be available on all mainstream distros and is probably installed by default.

Comment: Note that you can return an error without aborting the suspend by returning one of the special values defined in /usr/lib/pm-utils/pm-functions : `$NA` is "not applicable", `$DX` is "disabled", and `$NX` is "not executable". See the `hook_exit_status` function in the pm-functions script

Comment: NOTE: This answer an more was provided to the OP on this Q: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62157/pm-utils-no-network-in-suspend-scripts I think he's looking for something else that doesn't exist wrt NetworkManager.

Comment: As I already said in the referenced question, I do not have any network in the scripts (i.e. 10-umount). As soon as any script executes, the network already is down.

Comment: I will investigate the `system connection` property. EDIT: It already was a `system connection`.

Comment: So I think this is a bug in NetworkManager --- system network connections should be guaranteed to stay for the 00-50 scripts. If you report a bug please post the link here, I will add myself to it.

Answer (score 3):

Building on what @ensc said, you could instead listen for that D-Bus (system session) signal yourself. The general workflow with the `org.freedesktop.login1.Manager` interface would be:

1. inhibit system sleep (maybe also shutdown) with `Inhibit(what, who, why, mode)`

   - `what`: `sleep` or `shutdown:sleep`
   - `who`: `unmount_cifs` or whatever you'll call your script
   - `why`: `unmounting cifs X before suspend ...` or equivalent
   - `mode`: `delay` to inhibit for a max. of 5s (default) or `block` to block indefinitely (I would recommend the first. If your script stalls, your notebook will just never go to sleep.)
   - this returns a file descriptor that 'holds' the lock
2. now you listen for the signal(s)

   - `PrepareForSleep`, which returns `True` when about to suspend or hibernate and `False` when resuming and thawing)
   - `PrepareForShutdown`, which returns `True` when about to shutdown and should return `False` when powering back on (instead it also returns `False` at the same time it returns `True` which makes no sense to me, so I would just ignore the `False` part here; you probably already have some kind of automounting script on system start anyways, don't you?)
3. as soon as you're done with handling the `True` signal (i.e. unmounting) you release the lock by closing the file descriptor (returned by `Inhibit(...)`), so that the machine may go to sleep or shutdown as fast as possible without waiting for the whole 5s (or even indefinitely when in `block` mode)
4. you can handle the `False` signal (resume/thaw) by remounting (maybe first waiting for the network to come back on) and then create a new lock with `Inhibit(...)` (for the next sleep or shutdown)

In Python (2.7) this could look like:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os, atexit, dbus, gobject
from dbus.mainloop import glib

def login1ManagerDBusIface():
    system_bus = dbus.SystemBus()
    proxy = system_bus.get_object( 'org.freedesktop.login1',
                                  '/org/freedesktop/login1' )
    login1 = dbus.Interface( proxy, 'org.freedesktop.login1.Manager')
    return login1

def sleepShutdownInhibit():
    login1 = login1ManagerDBusIface()
    fd = login1.Inhibit( 'shutdown:sleep', 'unmount_cifs',
                         'Unmounting before suspend/shutdown ...',
                         'delay' )
    return fd

def take_lock():
    global FD
    FD = sleepShutdownInhibit()

def remove_lock():
    global FD
    if FD:
        os.close( FD.take() )
        FD = None

def signal_handler(boolean, member=None):
    if boolean:  ## going to suspend/hibernate or shutdown
        ## PLACE YOUR UNMOUNT STUFF HERE
        remove_lock()
    else:  ## resume/thaw
        if member == 'PrepareForSleep':
            ## PLACE YOUR MOUNT STUFF HERE
            take_lock()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    take_lock()
    atexit.register(remove_lock)
    login1 = login1ManagerDBusIface()
    for signal in ['PrepareForSleep', 'PrepareForShutdown']:
        login1.connect_to_signal(signal, signal_handler,
                                 member_keyword='member')
    glib.DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)
    loop = gobject.MainLoop()
    loop.run()
```

In [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/ste-fan/0fe2d14ced250c2ef962) you'll find my wrapper around Pidgin to disconnect IM accounts on sleep and shutdown, using exactly the same approach.

See also the official freedesktop documentation on [Inhibitor Locks](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/inhibit/) and the [`logind` D-Bus API](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/logind/).

Comment: I'm looking at doing something similar (for https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/337853). This sounds promising, but surely it is racing with NetworkManager which is doing the same thing? What happens if my network-dependent script takes longer to run than NetworkManager takes to stop the network?

Comment: Tried it out (https://github.com/davidn/av) and it seems to work!

Answer (score 1):

You could try to find out why `nm` is shutting down the devices:

```
dbus-monitor --system &
nmcli g logging level DEBUG
--> trigger suspend
```

When (like in my case (Fedora 20)), `systemd` is triggering the signal, you can deny its delivery in the dbus configuration:

```
---- /etc/dbus-1/system.d/99-my-suspend.conf ---
<busconfig>
        <policy user="root">
                <deny receive_interface="org.freedesktop.login1.Manager"
                      receive_type="signal"
                      receive_member="PrepareForSleep"/>
        </policy>
</busconfig>
```

Unfortunately, these rules are not very fine grained and it will block the `PrepareForSleep` signal for other processes too.

Answer (score 0):

Try to shutdown service before suspend and start again after resume. Like that:

http://oleeekchoff.blogspot.ie/2012/05/restart-modulesservices-after.html

Comment: What do you mean? Should I stop the network manager service? I do not understand how that would help.

Comment: welcome to Stack Exchange! please don't give answers that are basically single links. if possible, you should paraphrase the material you linked to, otherwise, copying and pasting is fine as long as you attribute it. and again, welcome!